# applying cut within dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, cut

I have a data frame as the following example:

```
  ID   <- 1:6
  DRUG <- c(1,1,0,1,0,0)
  PRD  <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
  MAX  <- c(15,20,50,18,80,350)

  df <- data.frame(ID,DRUG,PRD,MAX)
```

I want to bin `MAX` to a pre-defined intervals and make a summary by `DRUG` and `PRD` for the number of `ID` in each category.

My data set is much bigger than the example provided.

Is there a way to do the binning and summary in R using `dplyr` or any other package?

I tried this `tapply(df$MAX,cut(df$MAX,4),length)` but it bins the data to equal intervals which is not the thing I want to achieve. Also, It doesn't give summary by `DRUG` and `PRD`.

**Update**: I came up with a better solution to facet by variables in the data frame; however, if the interval has `NA` number of observed data, then it doesn't keep it in the output summary. How can I still keep it in my summary? and how can make the output as a percentage in addition to reporting `n`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(DRUG,PRD,cut(MAX,breaks=c(0,20,40,60,Inf))) %>%
  summarise(n=n())
```

This gives:

```
   DRUG   PRD cut(MAX, breaks = c(0, 20, 40, 60, In...     n
  (dbl) (dbl)                                   (fctr) (int)
1     0     2                                  (40,60]     1
2     0     3                                 (60,Inf]     2
3     1     1                                   (0,20]     2
4     1     2                                   (0,20]     1
```

So here, for example, the interval from (0,15] for `DRUG==0` and `PRD==2` doesn't appear in the summary because there isn't any value within this interval. How can I have all the intervals there even if there isn't any value within that interval (It should give `NA` instead)? Also, how can i add a calculated percentage based on the total number of `ID` in each `DRUG` and `PRD` category?

Comment: There are many worked examples on SO. Do search with a few of the keywords in your question title.

Comment: see, `cut`, `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarise`.

Comment: @jeremycg the examples I've seen with cut is you define the number of intervals but not the intervals themselves which is not the goal here. I want to manually define them.

Comment: `cut(df$MAX, breaks = c(0, 15, 30, 60, 100, Inf)))`

Comment: Please read the help pages when considering a possible function. It should have been very clear on ?cut that it could accept an argument for `breaks`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments and what you have tried, you can use the following:

```
tapply(df$MAX,cut(df$MAX, breaks = c(0, 15, 30, 60, 100, Inf)),length)
```

Comment: However, I still need to subset the data but I can manage that.